# No toolbar for Chrome in Gnome

Tags: gnome, google-chrome

I installed and am running Gnome DE, but there is no more application toolbar for Google Chrome.

Toolbars for other apps, such as LibreOffice or Shotwell, work just fine, but whatever the window theme, Chrome toolbar is simply non-existent.

Works fine in Unity DE.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: Also, what toolbar are you speaking of? Do you mean the bookmarks bar?

Comment: "File," "Edit," et cetera.

Comment: I see. Click on the 'Google Chome' menu in the top panel (next to 'Activities'). Gnome puts menus there.

Comment: Interesting.  All I have there is "Quit."  Other apps have the menus in toolbar format as well.

Comment: There was a setting in chrome://settings, "Use system borders" or similar. Try changing that.

Comment: Are you sure chrome *has* a menu? Because I use chrome, and I've never seen it... Also, why would chrome *need* a menu? It has no need for File, Edit, etc — it has all options in the "three-dots" menu.

Comment: @BharadwajRaju Sure it does. For example, for opening a file without typing `file:///` etc. by hand. It was there in Unity and disappeared in Gnome.

Answer (score 1):

Click on the three-vertical-dot button on the top left corner of your google chrome window to access the menu.

Comment: Basically, your answer rephrases last comment.

Comment: That comment should have been an answer.